# Running .bat file whenever a user is logged in

Tags: c#, registrykey

I want a `.bat` file to run whenever the machine starts (or alternatively whenever a user is signed in)

For this I've made this piece of code:

```
            string subKey = "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run";
            RegistryKey key;
            if (ClientSystem.Is64BitOperatingSystem)
            {
                key = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(
                    RegistryHive.LocalMachine, 
                    RegistryView.Registry64
                ).OpenSubKey(subKey);
            }
            else
            {
                key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(subKey, true);
            }
            key.SetValue("websocket", @"c:\websocket\run.bat"); // error here
```

when running this I get an error telling me that I don't have permission change the file.

As @Tolanj mentions it might be an idea to add the actual error message:

> Der kan ikke skrives til registreringsdatabasenøglen.

Which would translate to something like

> Couldn't write to the database registration key

The user running the program has adminstrator rights and the program is run as administrator

How would I go around changing the permission in order to allow the script to be run when the machine starts or is there a better  way to achieve the functionality I'm looking for?

Comment: 'I get an error telling me that I don't have permission change the file' => post the actual, exact error message.

Comment: @tolanj: I don't know how useful the error: "Der kan ikke skrives til registreringsdatabasenøglen." is for you. Which is why I didn't add it ;-)

Comment: When does the error occur? Is it the `.OpenSubKey()`, the `.SetValue()` or does it happen when the run.bat file is running?

Comment: @Michael its very useful because its saying you don't have permission to change the registry rather than a file permission issue

Comment: You're trying to update HKLM so you'll need to run with admin permissions (ie run as Administrator etc) are you?

Comment: @Oliver: The error happens on the key.SetValue

Comment: @tolanj: I get the same error when running the program as administrator

Comment: Are you on 64bit?  because your 64bit branch does not have OpenSubKey(String, Boolean) and thus is readonly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
                key = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(
                RegistryHive.LocalMachine, 
                RegistryView.Registry64
            ).OpenSubKey(subKey);
```

needs to be:

```
                key = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(
                RegistryHive.LocalMachine, 
                RegistryView.Registry64
            ).OpenSubKey(subKey, true);
```

to open for modify